# Why Passing parcelable data from one activity and receiving in another it is partly modifed?

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

Pass parcelable data from one activity to another ,while in Activity2 where  I need to get the passed data.it is partly modified (the arraylist part)

I set these values
year  Year 19.99
while receive such results
null null 1.3796130171011302E-306

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
 intent.putExtra("SELECTED_ITEM", item);


public class Activity2 extends FragmentActivity 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent data = getIntent();
    selectedItem = data.getExtras().getParcelable("SELECTED_ITEM");

}
}


@Element(name = "data")
public class Data  implements Parcelable {
    @Element(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    @ElementList(name = "iap_subscription_packages", required = false)
    private ArrayList<Subscription> iapSubscription;



    Data() {
    }

    Data(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public ArrayList<Subscription> getSubscription() {
        return subscription;
    }

    public void setSubscription(ArrayList<Subscription> subscription) {
        this.iapSubscription = iapSubscription;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeList(iapSubscription);

    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {

        id = in.readString();
        iapSubscription = new ArrayList<Subscription>();
        if (iapSubscription != null) {
            in.readTypedList(iapSubscription, Subscription.CREATOR);
        }
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public Data createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Data(in);
        }

        public Data[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Data[size];
    }


   };

}




@Element(name = "package")
public class Subscription  implements Parcelable {
    Subscription() {
    }

    Subscription(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    @Element(name = "cycle", required = false)
    private String cycle;
    @Element(name = "name", required = false)
    private String name;
    @Element(name = "price", required = false)
    private double subscriptionPrice;

    public String getCycle() {
        return cycle;
    }

    public void setCycle(String cycle) {
        this.cycle = cycle;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getSubscriptionPrice() {
        return subscriptionPrice;
    }

    public void setSubscriptionPrice(double subscriptionPrice) {
        this.subscriptionPrice = subscriptionPrice;
    }
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(cycle);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeDouble(subscriptionPrice);
    Log.i("subscription", "writeToParcel " + cycle + " " + name + " " + subscriptionPrice);
}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {

   cycle = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    subscriptionPrice = in.readDouble();
    Log.i("subscription", "readFromParcel " + cycle + " " + name + " " + subscriptionPrice);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public Subscription createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Subscription(in);
    }

    public Subscription[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Subscription[size];
    }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the code you posted what you are actually testing with?

This method has an error:

```
public void setSubscription(ArrayList<Subscription> subscription) {
    this.iapSubscription = iapSubscription;
}
```

You probably wanted this:

```
public void setSubscription(ArrayList<Subscription> subscription) {
    this.iapSubscription = subscription;
}
```

I copied your code and tested the parts related to Parceleable.  That seems to be correct.  I was able to parcel and unparcel an ArrayList of Subscriptions.

If you are still having problems, post the code for where you build the bundle for the intent.